# DateTime subtraction not working in PowerShell - assignment vs. equality operator

Tags: powershell, syntax, operators, equality-operator

Today (2017-05-29) I am using PowerShell 5.0.10586.117 on Windows 7 Enterprise and run the following (shortened):

```
$dateOfLicense = "2017-04-20"
$dateOfToday = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f (Get-Date)

$TimeDifference = [DateTime]$dateOfToday - [DateTime]$dateOfLicense 
if (($TimeDifference) = 14)
{
    Write-Host "test"
}
```

Even the difference between both days is 39, my code jumps in the if-clause and sends "test" to screen.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are *assigning* `14` to `$TimeDifference`. Instead you wan't to compare the `Days` property using `-le`:

```
if ($TimeDifference.Days -le 14)
{
    Write-Host "test"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To *complement* [Martin Brandl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44243517/45375):

Like many other languages - but unlike VBScript, for instance - **PowerShell** uses distinct symbols for:

- the ***assignment* operator (`=`)**
- vs. the ***equality* test operator (`-eq`)**.

This distinction **enables using assignments as *expressions***, which is what you inadvertently did:

```bash
# !! ALWAYS $true
if ($TimeDifference = 14) ... # same as: if (($TimeDifference) = 14) ...
```

***assigns* `14` to variable `$TimeDifference`**, as Martin explains, and, because the assignment is enclosed in `(...)` - of necessity, to serve as a conditional for `if` - **evaluates to the assigned value** (the *inner* `(...)` around `$TimeDifference` make no difference here, however) and ***that* value is used as the conditional for `if`**.

That is, the `(...)` expression evaluated by `if` has value `14` - a *nonzero* number - and is therefore interpreted as `$true` in this Boolean context, irrespective of the original value of `$TimeDifference` - in other words: **your conditional is *always* `$true`**.

Note:

- To learn more about **PowerShell's operators**, run [`Get-Help about_Operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators)
- To learn about **how PowerShell interprets arbitrary values as Booleans in conditionals** (to-Boolean coercion), see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).
- **To test variables or expressions that already *are* Booleans**, just use them *as-is* or, if necessary, negate them with `-not` (`!`); e.g.:

  ```bash
  if ($someBoolean) {      # Better than: if ($someBoolean -eq $true)
  if (-not $someBoolean) { # Better than: if ($someBoolean -eq $false)
  ```

---

Finally, here's a **streamlined version of your code** that doesn't require intermediate variables, uses a *cast* to convert the string to a `[datetime]` instance and uses `[datetime]::now`, the more efficient equivalent of `Get-Date` (though that will rarely matter).

```bash
if (([datetime]::now - [datetime] '2017-04-20').Days -eq 14) {
  "test"
}
```

<sup>Note how `"test"` as a statement by itself implicitly sends output to PowerShell's (success) output stream, which prints to the console by default.

`Write-Host` bypasses this stream and [should generally be avoided](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Not better solution of Martin, just an shorty code

```
$dateOfLicense = [DateTime]"2017-04-20"
$TimeDifferenceDays = ((Get-Date) - $dateOfLicense).Days 

if ($TimeDifferenceDays -lt 14)
{
    Write-Host "test"
}
```